# Disappearing bounty on a question

Tags: support, specific-question, bounties

I submitted [an answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235050/accessing-a-web-service-from-your-browser/2250793#2250793) that was offering a bounty that is due to run out today. When I checked it this morning, the little banner saying that there was an open bounty is gone.

I don't think the bounty time limit is up yet, but if it was, my question is the highest rated with at least 2 upvotes, so I was expecting half the bounty.

Comment: The -50 rep on the poster's user page shows that I wasn't imagining things and there really was a bounty

Comment: You can't expect people to know which question you're vaguely talking about.

Comment: You don't get auto-accept if you posted your answer before the bounty run: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: @random didn't think it was needed, was a generic problem, but was willing to post the link if needed. Marc seems to have covered it anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The auto-accept runs on a delay - it isn't immediate. You now have half of the 100 bounty (I don't think anyone did anything). Through fluke of timing, in the past I've actually had bounty answers accepted by the OP *after* the bounty expired and *before* the auto-accept kicked in, so full bonus ;-p But not today...