# Where has the bounty gone?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disappearing bounty on a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39880/disappearing-bounty-on-a-question)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480634/examples-of-ll1-lr1-lr0-lalr1-grammars/6575862#6575862) had a +200 bounty and I see that bounty rules report the following text:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

I am wondering: Who has got the bounty?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The time for auto-awarding of bounties has been [extended by 24 hours:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68050/133693)

> I decided it can't hurt to extend the auto-award period 24 hours past the true end of the bounty. So, the question will stop being a bounty question at the original scheduled time but the auto-accept calculations will always occur 24 hours after that.

Comment: So can the person who asked the Q award bounty to someone else in that 24 hr period???

Comment: @xs2bush No, they can't.

Comment: whats the point of the buffer then???

Comment: @xs2bush Sorry I was mistaken. I believe the bounty can be awarded to anyone in the 24 hour period. The auto-accept however, will happen only after the 24 hours have passed