# Can the bounty buffer UI be made more consistent/clear?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, user-interface

So, I saw this inconsistent thing in the UI:

[image]

Then, I got to look whether a bounty is still going or not:

[image]

That clearly looks like a bounty is still going. Is it? *Reads again...* Oh, it **had** a bounty that **ended**.

Very confusing behavior if you ask me, this made me wonder what this inconsistency was for.

This revealed [Where has the bounty gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97608/where-has-the-bounty-gone/97609#97609), which makes some kind of sense to help people.

---

**However, it's very inconsistent and unclear to most visitors in it's current way, so I suggest:**

- Removal from the featured list, there is no point in the questing still being there after expiration.
- A more descriptive message, add the following text: "and is awaiting assignment within X hours."

Comment: Bounty FAQ for others: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is related to a (relatively) recent feature request about giving users with bounties more time to choose a winner. I think this happens when the bounty has run out, but no pick has been made yet

Comment: @EatmoreTwisters: As I [outlined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97608/where-has-the-bounty-gone/97609#97609) in my question I know that, **I'm asking for clarification/improvement**.

Comment: @Tom ah, fair enough - I didn't realize that was that request.

Comment: @Eatmore: FYI: The boldness isn't meant personal, but rather preventive for further commenters...

Comment: @Eat actually, it was entirely unrelated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply a bug - related to caching and a copy of "now" (time) that was being used long after it was overdue. [The full details are here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSSGiA4f5cs).